# Power Query map one column from a table to three columns of another table

Tags: excel, join, powerbi, powerquery, slicers

I am working on a dashboard for Netflix movies/series. I have a table **A** with columns as shown -
[image]

I need a Genre Slicer on the top of dashboard to filter movies of that genre.

I am thinking of making an another table **B** with column Only_Genre such as -

[image]

and separating the Genre column from table **A** into different columns as shown -
[image]

and then mapping Only_Genre of table **B** to Genre, Genre2 and Genre3 of table **A**.

But I am unable to do so in power query. Can anyone please help?
Or any other workaround for the job can also work. Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the dashboard and your slicer? Depending on what you are doing, it's simple to filter (the Genre column) based on `contains`, or, in PQ, to split the Genre column and then unpivot to result in a single Genre per line table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making table `B` like this:

| Genre | Single Genre |
| --- | --- |
| Crime, Drama, Mystery | Crime |
| Crime, Drama, Mystery | Drama |
| Crime, Drama, Mystery | Mystery |
| Crime, Drama | Crime |
| Crime, Drama | Drama |
| Action, Crime, Thriller | Action |
| Action, Crime, Thriller | Crime |
| Action, Crime, Thriller | Thriller |

Then you can create a relationship on `Genre` and use `Single Genre` for your slicer. You'll want it to be many-to-many where `B` filters `A`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. This seems a better way to deal with the problem. But I am not sure how to make one row into number of rows as per its content in power query. Such as Crime, Drama, Mystery into 3 rows and Crime, Drama into 2 rows. Would you please help me with that? Much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: In the query editor, you can create a column that splits the text into a list `Text.Split([Genre],", ")` and then expand that list column to new rows.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis for all your help.